# Preserve data in table from a View to another

Tags: ios, swift3

I'm trying to send values from one view to other and print them in a table as an array. The program work and display the data but the problem is that when I try to add another value to the table when I return to the view that have the table the previous values are no longer there.

[image: Here is the story board the view of the left have the tables to display the data and the one of the right is where I add the data]

In this segment of code I sent the data to the other view

```
import UIKit



class NewContactoViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

var contacto: String = ""
var numero: String = ""

@IBOutlet weak var contactoField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var numField: UITextField!

let defaultValues = UserDefaults.standard

@IBAction func addButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    contacto = contactoField.text!
    numero = numField.text!

}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    var secondController = segue.destination as! ContactosViewController

    secondController.contactos = contactoField.text!
    secondController.numerosmov = numField.text!

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.contactoField.delegate = self
    self.numField.delegate = self

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

In this segment of code are the tableviews that display the data

```
import UIKit

class ContactosViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

let defaultValues = UserDefaults.standard

var contactos: String = ""
var numerosmov: String = ""
var tablacontacto = [String] ()
var tablanumero = [String] ()

let cellIdentifier: String = "cell"
let cellIdentifier2: String = "cell2"


@IBOutlet weak var contactoTable: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var numTable: UITableView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: navigationController, action: nil)
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    datosRecividos(contactos, numerosmov)
    contactoTable.delegate = self
    numTable.delegate = self
    contactoTable.dataSource = self
    numTable.dataSource = self
    contactoTable!.reloadData()
    numTable!.reloadData()
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    contactoTable.reloadData()
    numTable.reloadData()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func datosRecividos(_ contactosr: String, _ numerosr: String)
{
tablacontacto.append(contactosr)
    tablanumero.append(numerosr)
    let usercontacto = defaultValues.array(forKey: "contactoTable")
    let usernumero = defaultValues.array(forKey: "numeroTable")

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if (tableView.tag == 1)
    {
    return(tablacontacto.count)
    }
    else if (tableView.tag == 2)
    {
    return(tablanumero.count)
    }
    return 0
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath)

    if (tableView.tag == 1)
    {
    cell.textLabel?.text = tablacontacto[indexPath.row] as! String

    }
    else if (tableView.tag == 2)
    {
       cell.textLabel?.text = tablanumero[indexPath.row] as! String

    }

    return(cell)
}





}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several things wrong here, I would suggest reading again about tableView's (especially the "Load Initial Data" section) -

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/CreateATableView.html

Your tables are getting data from the "tablacontacto" and "tablanumero" arrays.
There is no place in the code you sent to populate these arrays. (Do you see anything when these tables are on screen?)

Plus You are updating these arrays with only in the "func datosRecividos(_ contactosr: String, _ numerosr: String)"  -
This method is only called once in the viewDidLoad and it is not called when you segue back to this screen

Plus you have no place you get data to your arrays from your userDefaults and there is no place you save the "new" data from "NewContactoViewController" to your userDefaults.

Comment: Yes, when I run the project I can add values in the tables, and the tables display the data, the problem is that when I try to add more data the previous data is no longer there and only the new data is display.

Comment: @EdwinLima can you show me the code you use to show the data in the tables : "Yes, when I run the project I can add values in the tables, and the tables display the data"?

Answer (score 0):

Make this two variables as static variables

```
internal static var CONTACTTO: String = ""
internal static var NUMERO: String = ""
```

then access this variables using,

```
NewContactoViewController.CONTACTTO
NewContactoViewController.NUMERO
```

Then there is no need sending this values using

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        var secondController = segue.destination as! ContactosViewController

        secondController.contactos = contactoField.text!
        secondController.numerosmov = numField.text!

}
```

Or otherwise you can save these values in shared preferences

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a delegate for data changing in NewContactoViewController

```
import UIKit

//Create a delegate for data changing
protocol ContactChageDelegate: class {
    func contactChanged(newContact: String, newNumber: String)
}

class NewContactoViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
//declare delegate variable
weak var contactChageDelegate: ContactChageDelegate?
...



@IBAction func addButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    contacto = contactoField.text!
    numero = numField.text!

    //if need notify data changing. maybe it will not change
    //if data change {
        self.contactChageDelegate.contactChanged(newContact: contacto, newNumber: numero)
    //}
}
```

and use this delegate in ContactosViewController like this:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    //let self to delegate
    if let newContactoViewController = segue.destination as? NewContactoViewController {
        newContactoViewController.contactChageDelegate = self
    }
}

...

//implement delegate method
extension ContactosViewController: ContactChageDelegate {
    internal func contactChanged(newContact: String, newNumber: String) {
          //now you have new values
          //change your data array
          //and reload table
    }
}
```